# Bind BorderBrush in Code-Behind

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to do the following in code-behind (C#)?  I want to bind the `BorderBrush` in code-behind (the border element is a child inside a `DataGrid` cell and the color of this border must match the color specified for the DataGrid's vertical grid lines color)

```
<Border BorderBrush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=VerticalGridLinesBrush}" BorderThickness="0 0 1 0" Grid.Column="0">
    <TextBlock Name="tbMyBlock" Text="My Text Block" />
</Border>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this in code behind? Bindings aren't that hard to create in code behind anyway. You'll find many examples on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why do you want to create the binding programmatically?

Comment: @mm8, I want to create a binding in code-behind because I need to dynamically generate columns in my DataGrid, columns whose headers and values come from a collection of objects a part of my DataContext via ViewModel bound to entities through EF

Comment: @Ed Plunkett, the question wasn't how to do bindings in code-behind (although I could have re-phrased the question better), the main question I have is how to bind to an existing color of a control defined in the XAML.

Comment: @J-man If you already know how to do bindings in C#, how is that a problem? Anyway, you should do this in XAML. Define a template in xaml as a resource.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of doing binding with a `SetBinding` call on my border object, I am setting the property directly:

```
border.SetValue(Border.BorderBrushProperty, MyDataGrid.HorizontalGridLinesBrush);
```

Comment: Better just write `border.BorderBrush = MyDataGrid.HorizontalGridLinesBrush;`